# React webpack application not loading Roboto Font

Tags: reactjs, fonts, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am working on React application where i want to use Roboto Font.I have followed the process to load the roboto Font. Following is my Project Structure :

[image]

My Index.css file

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: 'Roboto-Light';
        src: url('./Roboto-Light.eot');
        src: url('./Roboto-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('./Roboto-Light.woff') format('woff'),
             url('./Roboto-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('./Roboto-Light.svg#RobotoLight') format('svg');
        font-weight: 100;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

My webpack.config.js :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { resolve } = require('path');
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'js/index'),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?sourceMap&camelCase&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          'sass-loader?sourceMap'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'url-loader?limit=1024&name=images/[name].[ext]'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        use: ['file-loader?name=src/fonts/[name].[ext]']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(json)$/,
        use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]']
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and using css to load font as :

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto-Light' !important;
}
```

I have followed [this](https://shellmonger.com/2016/01/22/working-with-fonts-with-webpack/) tutorial but its not working as expected and font is not loaded on webpage. Thanks in advance.

I didnt got any solution as of now.

Added Screenshot as per requested[image]

Comment: Could you push your code to github?

Comment: I will try to put it on github..

Comment: https://github.com/rahul-naik/react-webpack chk here

Answer (score 0):

Look like the app couldn't load the font face.

Please try:

1. in **src/js/index.js**: remove the line

   import '../fonts/index.css';
2. rename file **index.css** to **roboto.scss**
3. in **src/fonts/roboto.scss** use absolute path instead of relative path:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto-Light';
    src: url('/src/fonts/Roboto-Light.eot');
    src: url('/src/fonts/Roboto-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/src/fonts/Roboto-Light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/src/fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/src/fonts/Roboto-Light.svg#RobotoLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

4. in **src/css/styles.scss** add:

   @import "../fonts/roboto";

You can also take a look at [this](https://github.com/jaredchu/react-webpack/commit/57dff0efe0158f18d9a78c38b8e94de92f4e5fdc) commit.

**Update 1**
You can use [WhatFont](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en) chrome extension to check. it's Roboto Light.
[image: update 1]

**Update 2**

I found that you must use absolute http url because app can't find your font with normal path.

**src/fonts/roboto.scss**

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto-Light';
    src: url('http://localhost:8089/fonts/Roboto-Light.eot');
    src: url('http://localhost:8089/fonts/Roboto-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://localhost:8089/fonts/Roboto-Light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://localhost:8089/fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://localhost:8089/fonts/Roboto-Light.svg#RobotoLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And the result:
[image: update 2]

Comment: see I have updated question and added screenshot which is definitely not having Roboto.
fyi, I have used your commit

Comment: no its not Roboto-Light !! I have already developed static HTML for this with Roboto-Light and it looks very different. I am 100% sure that its not Roboto-Light though :(

Comment: ah, I see the problem, I will check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150291/discussion-between-jared-chu-and-rahul-naik).